# Android Realm - Is it Possible to Update and Delete Objects Without Need For ID, Like In Swift

Tags: android, swift, realm

I have been looking for a clear answer to this for a while but had not been able to find one, so posting it here.

For my `Message` class, to delete or update a message, I can do this in Swift:

**To Delete:**

```
func delete() {
    guard let realm = realm else {return}
    try! realm.write {
        realm.delete(self)
    }
}
```

**To Update:**

```
func update(_ messageText: String) {
    guard let realm = realm else {return}
    try! realm.write {
        .message_text = messageText
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way to delete and update on Android? What I have been finding so far is pretty ugly and complex, and requires unique IDs as well for the objects. Is this the only way to do it in Android? I don't want IDs for my objects. IDs seems counterintuitive for Realm and my objects don't have them either.

**To Delete:**

```
public void delete(String id, Realm realm) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(realm1 -> {
            RealmResults<Message> results = realm.where(Message.class).equalTo("id", id).findAll();
            results.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }, (Realm.Transaction.OnError) RealmLog::error);
}
```

**To Update:**

```
public void update(String id, String messageText, Realm realm) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(realm1 -> {
        Message m = realm1.where(Message.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
        if (m != null) {
            m.updated = date;
            realm1.insertOrUpdate(m);
        }
    }, (Realm.Transaction.OnError) RealmLog::error);
}
```

Comment: Well you need to query items and then edit them in a transaction.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce like I am doing in the above delete and update sample code? Or there is some other way to do it?

Comment: This is the way to do it, but you don't necessarily need an ID specifically to find the object. You do want to identify it in some way though.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce so as I understand, in order to plan for a Realm schema, which will be used both for Android and iOS, it is necessary to define some sort of unique ID because Android version will require it.

Comment: It's not technically required, but how else do you intend to find the object? Also, it's safer to be able to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` than not.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I didn't want to find the object, I was simply passing the object as an argument, like I do in Swift, but in Android I get ```Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.``` error message. Why exact same logic becomes outside of write transaction in Android but not in Swift, that's what's core of my confusion.

Comment: `realm.write {` is same as `realm.executeTransaction(() -> {});`